# How to imitate sql query in Spring Data using query

Tags: java, spring-data

I create query in mysql database

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.seanceDate, COUNT(r.seanceDate) 
FROM reservation r 
GROUP BY r.seanceDate
ORDER BY COUNT(r.seanceDate) DESC
```

and try do copy this to java spring repository

```
@Query("SELECT distinct r.seanceDate, count(r.seanceDate) from reservation r group by r.seanceDate order by count(r.seanceDate) desc")
public List<ReservationCountSeanceDto> findCountSeanceDate();
```

i create model ReservationCountSeanceDto

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReservationCountSeanceDto {
    private java.time.LocalDate seanceDate;
    private Integer count;
}
```

and my Reservation Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reservation")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Reservation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    private java.time.LocalDate reservationDate;
    private java.time.LocalDate seanceDate;

    private Integer reservationNr;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Seance reservationSeance;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User userReservation;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<Seat> seats = new ArrayList<>();
}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reservationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List ...ReservationRepository.findCountSeanceDate()!
```

How to create properly this query in spring data ?

Comment: try `SELECT new com.to.packagename.ReservationCountSeanceDto(distinct com.r.seanceDate, count(r.seanceDate)) from ...`

Comment: @YCF_L @Query("SELECT new com.wojciech.app.repositories.ReservationRepository(distinct com.wojciech.app.repositories.ReservationRepository.r.seanceDate, count(r.seanceDate)) from reservation r group by r.seanceDate order by count(r.seanceDate) desc") in this syntax i have error

Comment: you can also try `public List<Object[]> findCountSeanceDate();` then you can loop over this list and cast each value to create a new Object of type `ReservationRepository` this should work with you

Comment: @YCF_L I must cast this to Entity type if would like return List contains only two field count and date?

Comment: yes your code can be `List<Object[]> list = repo.findCountSeanceDate();
List<Object[]> listReservationCountSeanceDto = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object[] o : list){
    listReservationCountSeanceDto.add(new ReservationCountSeanceDto((java.time.LocalDate)o[0], (Integer)o[1]));
}`

Comment: @YCF_L i use this code and still have error

Comment: ..which error ?

Comment: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.wojciech.app.repositories.ReservationRepository.findCountSeanceDate()!

Comment: It seems that your query is not correct

Comment: In Mysql work fine this must be syntax error in Java Hibernate

Comment: you still can try with `nativeQuery=true`

Comment: @YCF_L today you are my hero

Comment: Amazing knowladge and experience

Comment: does it work with you?

Comment: Yes with nativeQuery this work fine, don't have error

Comment: nice to hear that, I'm sure that there are a better solution to your problem without nativeQuery, I'm sorry I'm tired good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i suppose that you help solve problems for many hours

Answer (score 0):

You can get result it List of DTO with JPA query like:

```
@Query("SELECT distinct NEW com.mypackage.Test(r.constractStartDate as seanceDate, count(r.active) as seanceDateCount) from reservation r group by r.constractStartDate order by count(r.active) desc")
public List<Test> findCountSeanceDate();

System.out.println(jobContractRepository.findCountSeanceDate().get(0).getSeanceDate());
```

Make sure count field must defined as long datatype in DTO

Also you can get result in List of Map to access value based on key but alias name of column is require in query

```
@Query("SELECT distinct r.seanceDate as seanceDate, count(r.seanceDate) as seanceDateCount  from reservation r group by r.seanceDate order by count(r.seanceDate) desc")
public List<Map<String, Object>> findCountSeanceDate();
```

And you can access like this:

```
System.out.println(jobContractRepository.findCountSeanceDate().get(0).get("seanceDateCount"));
```